# How to find an index of an attribute in core data

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data, swift2, xcode7

I found how to find the index of an element in an array:

```
let arr = ["a","b","c"]

let indexOfA = arr.indexOf("a") //0
let indexOfB = arr.indexOf("b") //1
let indexOfC = arr.indexOf("c") //2
```

Is there a way to apply this to Core Data to find the index of a certain attribute? Lets say I have an entity called Events. In Events there is 3 attributes: eventName, eventLocation, eventDate. If there are many events saved is there a way to enter, for example, one of the names saved and return the index that it is located in similar to the way above?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly in Core Data, because Core Data doesn't sort the data, so there is no first, second, third, etc, there are just a bunch of instances. When you fetch data from Core Data via `NSFetchRequest`, you can tell it how to sort the results, using the `sortDescriptors` property. The fetch request gives you an array of results, sorted according to those descriptors. You could then find the index of an event name in that array.